# Entity Frame 4 Tiers

Tags: entity-framework

I'm going to use entity framework 4.  I am looking to try and separate the business entity classes from the context, is this possible?  I think I saw it some where, but have no idea where I saw this.  I know that you have to set something in the templates.

Can someone please help me on the right path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Simple Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321569.aspx#id0090012)

Closest quick start i could find was by Scott Hanselman where he walks you through [Code First Entities](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx)